# Installing wp3.2.1 on IIS; getting empty sessions

Tags: php, admin, loop, installation, iis

i have to install wordpress 3.2.1 on IIS 5.0 (yeah, i know...) here. Brand new default wordpress installation, no plugins ore previous versions installed. 
So, i downloaded the 3.2.1.zip and the 3.2.1-IIS.zip, unzipped everything and set up the database, but i get the same issue every time:

everything works, except when i try to login to the admin area it keeps redirecting me back to `wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` without any error message.

config:

1. all requests to http://www.mydomain.com are rewritten to http://mydomain.com
2. tbl wp_options has `siteurl` and `home` set to `http://mydomain.com`
3. i can see 2 cookies: `wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check` and `PHPSESSID=617cdf1966c78a56e2dd901942d41124` in my browser
4. there is an empty file `sess_617cdf1966c78a56e2dd901942d41124` in my session folder

It looks like a session problem to me. I have a cookie set in my browser, and there is a corresponding session file in my webservers session folder, but it's always empty (0 Bytes).

when i create a simple test script in the same folder as my wp-installation and manually add

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

then i can also see those values in my session files.

For the last 2 days i tried to figure out whats wrong here. The installed php files and my database are both ok, it works as it should when i moved the installation to a diffent xampp webserver on a different box. Crosschecked my php.ini and the session handling is the same as on xampp.

I pretty much tried out any suggestion i found on wordpress.org and other forums for this topic; but nothings seem to work.

Comment: As far as I was aware WP doesn't use sessions... I did a search for `session_start(` in WP core files and there isn't a single occurrence. Are you sure sessions are your issue?

Comment: Like Brady mentioned WordPress does not use Session. If you are having trouble login in you might want to clear your browser cache/cookies for the site and try again.

Comment: Yeah i tried that, but clearing cache and cookies didn't help; and i tried it in Chrome, FF and Opera.

If it dosn't uses $_SESSION, where does it store my login info then? Cookies...?

Comment: Are you forced to use IIS 5.0? What is 3.2.1-IIS.zip? Is it a hacked version of 3.2.1? Have you checked your PHP error logs? Also, what are the permissions on your PHP installation?

Comment: Have you tried logging in on different browsers (specifically IE). Also, have you checked your IIS log file for 401.x errors?

Answer (score 1):

Check out your php.ini config file and try changing the permissions for your upload_tmp_dir & session.save_path directories.